# Expected wealth of coin toss game with stop loss

Tags: probability, finance, random-walk

You start with an initial wealth $\$X$. The coin toss game is such that where the coin is flipped $100$ times and for every heads the players get - they receive $\$2$, else they lose $\$1$.
There is a stop loss at $\$0$, namely if the current wealth ever reaches $0, the game ends. 
What is the expected wealth?

Attempts and thoughts:

The game is a random walk, and its simple to compute the expected wealth without the stop loss. If we take $Z_i$ to be +2 with probability $1/2$ else $-1$ with probability $1/2$, then $S_k = \sum_{i=1}^{k}Z_i$, and one can show that $S_k - \frac{1}{2} t$ is a martingale, thus $\mathbb{E}[S_T] = T/2$. So, clearly the player expects to make $\$50$.

I have tried simulating this on python (taking an initial wealth to be zero):

```
   av = []
   for simulation in range(0,1000):
       s = 0
       l = 0
       for toss in range(0,100):
           x = np.random.randint(0,2)
           if x == 1:
               s+=2
           elif x == 0:
               s-=1

           if s <= 0:
               break
       av.append(s)
    print(np.array(av).mean())
```

from which I get a mean of about 16.45 or so. I am finding it difficult to work backwards and rationalise this result.

Can anyone at least point me in the right direction (just a hint/useful method please)? I'm familiar with the basic statements of optional stopping theorem (used earlier, if this can be used?).

Comment: For any $X\geq50$ the expected wealth is $X+50$

Comment: These types of problems often require tricky combinatorics to count the number of paths which satisfy the conditions. For a random walk with steps of ±1, the reflection principle allows you to find exact probabilities of having a final wealth of $k$ without ever reaching $0$. For steps of +2/–1, the same trick does not work...

Comment: @MikeEarnest Actually, this question is part of a set of quant interview questions. They did not require the actual expected wealth to be computed, rather if the expected wealth is larger with/without the stop loss. Numerically, I can show that if you have an initial wealth of $\$50$ it does not matter. However, if you have $\$0$ initial wealth, its the expected wealth is larger without stop loss. bkarthik is onto something, not sure who to reach this conclusion rigorously however.

Comment: Oh, you asked "what is the expected wealth?", which sounded like you wanted an exact answer. However, Manan's answer gives you exactly what you want; the expected profit is $E[T]/2$, which is less than 100/2 since there is a positive probability that $T<100$ (assuming the stop loss is possible to reach, which is true as long as $X<100$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, the stopping time $T$ is the minimum of $100$ coin flips, and the time to bankruptcy. So, on using the optional stopping theorem, we get $E[S_T]=E[T]/2$. In general, a player will get bankrupt before $100$ coin tosses, so $E[T]\neq 100$.